# PCRE regex with lookahead and lookbehind always returns true

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-lookarounds

I’m trying to create a regex for form validation but it always returns true. The user must be able to add something like `{user|2|S}` as input but also use brackets if they are escaped with `\`.

This code checks for the left bracket `{` for now.

```
$regex = '/({(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[0-9]*\|(S|D[0-9]*)}))|[^{]|(?<=\\\){)*/';
if (preg_match($regex, $value)) {
     return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

A possible correct input would be:

```
Hello {user|1|S}, you have {amount|2|D2}
```

or

```
Hello {user|1|S}, you have {amount|2|D2} in \{the_bracket_bank\}
```

However, this should return false:

```
Hello {user|1|S}, you have {amount|2}
```

and this also:

```
Hello {user|1|S}, you have {amount|2|D2} in {the_bracket_bank}
```

A live example can be found here: http://regexr.com?37tpu Note that there is a `\` in the lookbehind at the end, PHP was giving me error messages because I had to escape it an extra time in my code.

Comment: You'll probably find it easier to dump the third parameter of pregmatch (I.e. look at what's matching) and test each OR regex seperately. Documenting your regex would also help (you).

Comment: Why regex shouldn't match `Hello {user|1|S}, you have {amount|2|D2} in {the_bracket_bank} ` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is that you do not specify that the regex should match from the beginning to the of the checked string. Use the `^` and `$` assertions.

I think you have to escape `{` and `}` in your regex as they have special meaning. Together they form a quantifier.

The `(?<=\\\)` is better written `(?<=\\\\)`. The backslash has to be double escaped as it has special meaning in both single-quoted string and PCRE regex. Using `\\\` works too, because if single-quoted string contains any escape sequence except `\\` and `\'`, it handles it as literal backslash and letter, therefore `\)` is taken literally. But explicitly escaping the backslash twice seems easier to read to me.

The regex should be

```
$regex = '/^(\{(?=([a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[0-9]*\|(S|D[0-9]*)\}))|[^{]|(?<=\\\\)\{)*$/';
```

But notice that the look-around assertions are not necessary. This regex should do the job too:

```
$regex = '/^([^{]|\\\{|\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[0-9]*\|(S|D[0-9]*)\})*$/';
```

Any non-`{` characters are matched by the first alternative. When a `{` is read, one of the remaining two alternatives is used. Either the pattern for the brace thing matches, or the regex engine backtracks one character and tries to match `\{` character sequence. If it fails, both ways, it backtracks further till it reaches string start and fails completely.

Comment: works like a charm. Haven't tried it without the lookaround assertions , though

Answer (score 1):

### Matching without lookbehind

You can make a regex for this without using lookbehind/lookaheads (which is usually recommended).

For example, if your requirement is that you can match any character but a `{` and a `}` unless it's preceded by a `\`. You can also say:

Match any character but a `{` and a `}` OR match a `\{` or a `\}`. To match any character but a `{` and a `}` use:

```
[^{}]
```

To match a `\{` use:

```
\\\{
```

One backslash is for escaping the `{` (which might not be necessary, depending on your regex compiler) and one backslash is for escaping the other backslash.

You would end up with this:

```
(?:
    [^{}]
|
    \\\{
|
    \\\}
)+
```

I nicely formatted this regex so that it's readable. If you want to use it in your code like this make sure to use the `[PCRE_EXTENDED][1]` modifier.

Comment: Thanks for this great and nicely explained answer. This might work as well, but Palec's solution worked instantly and handled everything like it should

Comment: Yeah true, it is of course good possible in one regex. I'm not totally clear today either :P. I updated my answer to only include the explanation about matching without the lookarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Looks more of a job for a lookbehind to me:

```
/((?<!\\\\)\{[a-zA-Z0-9]+\|[0-9]+\|[SD][0-9]*\})/
```

However, the obfuscation factor is so high that I would rather recognize all bracketed strings and parse them later.